# Having trouble with accessing gpu of jetson nano for yolov8

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to run `yolov8` on gpu of jetson nano and don't have any specific knowledge about it. it would be helpful if you share you knowledge with me. i don't have knowledge of libraries which have to be installed to access gpu for `yolov8` for train and prediction.
I am expecting a guide for help.